# Inverter valor de y no canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Gostaria de saber se existe um meio de inverter o eixo y do `canvas` de modo que o ponto (0,0) na verdade seja o ponto (0,500).... 
Ou seja, se eu jogar o valor 20 no Y, em vez de começar de cima pra baixo, comece de baixo pra cima.....

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
function altera(valor, ponto) {
  document.getElementById('variavel_' + ponto).innerHTML = valor;

  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  desenhaBase(context, canvas);
}

function desenhaBase(context, canvas) {
  X = document.getElementById('valorX').value;
  Y = document.getElementById('valorY').value;
  X1 = document.getElementById('valorX1').value;
  Y1 = document.getElementById('valorY1').value;
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.fill();

  context.moveTo(X, Y);
  context.lineTo(X1, Y1);
  context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  context.stroke();
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;x1: <span id="variavel_x"></span>
    </td>
    <td>y1: <span id="variavel_y"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="range" style="width: 180px;" name="x" id="valorX" min="0" max="375" oninput="altera(this.value,this.name)">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="range" style="width: 180px;" name="y" id="valorY" min="0" max="500" oninput="altera(this.value,this.name)">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;x2: <span id="variavel_x1"></span>
    </td>
    <td>y2: <span id="variavel_y1"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="range" style="width: 180px;" name="x1" id="valorX1" min="0" max="375" oninput="altera(this.value,this.name)">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="range" style="width: 180px;" name="y1" id="valorY1" min="0" max="500" oninput="altera(this.value,this.name)">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="375" height="500"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se percebo bem a tua pergunta só precisas saber a altura do canvas `canvas.height` e subtrair a esse numero o `Y`, ou seja: `context.moveTo(X, canvas.height - Y);`

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mr6jqqc/

Comment: bom, com uma pequena ressalva @Sergio na linha debaixo, onde se define o Y1 tambêm deve se subtrair a altura, ai fica perfeito: `(X1, canvas.height - Y1); ` http://jsfiddle.net/4mr6jqqc/1/